# How to properly check that an off_t value won't overflow when converted to size_t in C?

Tags: c, posix

I need to cast an off_t variable to a size_t variable, and I want to detect if an overflow might happen. In C.

My initial attempts looks like this:

```
off_t fsize;
size_t len;

...

if(fsize >= 0 && fsize <= SIZE_MAX) {
   len = (size_t)fsize;
} else {
   abort();
}
```

However, the compiler doesn't like my comparison between a signed and unsigned types (fsize <= SIZE_MAX). I can't really make assumptions about the respective sizes of the off_t and size_t types either.

Comment: What kind of ISA are you compiling for where `size_t` might be "too small"? Are you on a system that allows for 128-bit filesizes?

Comment: Under which conditions can fsize be larger than SIZE_MAX?

Comment: `sizeof(off_t) <= sizeof(size_t)`? And considering that POSIX specifies `off_t` to be a *signed* type and `size_t` is *unsigned*, you can't really overflow the `size_t` type if that condition holds true. It may *underflow* though, if the `off_t` value is less than zero (like e.g. `-1`, which really should have been checked before).

Comment: `off_t` is signed type, `size_t` is unsigned.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: When a file size is larger than memory address space. E.g., a 6 GiB file on a system with 32-bit addressing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I fail to see your meaning. My point is that whatever value an off_t variable yields, it cannot be larger than SIZE_MAX. This is what Some programmer dude mentions.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: The value of an `off_t` can be larger than `SIZE_MAX`. `off_t` is a type for holding offsets in files. `size_t` is a type for holding sizes of objects. A C implementation might be able to work with very large files, using an `off_t` of 64 bits, but only able to handle in-memory objects of up to 2^32−1 bytes, using a `size_t` of 32 bits. Perhaps you and [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) are thinking of `ptrdiff_t` instead of `off_t`, which is for differences of pointers?

Comment: Yes, 32 bits, and even 16 bits, platforms are still around. http://synfare.com/599N105E/hwdocs/sizes.html  - It's mostly a theoretical point, but you never know where your code might end up, and more than one security bug started with somebody making assumptions like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't really make assumptions about the respective sizes of the off_t and size_t types either.

To compare mixed signed types whose comparable ranges are no clearly tied, cast to `uintmax_t`.

---

Once code knows the *signed* `fsize >= 0` is true, casting to a wide *unsigned* type like `uintmax_t` will certainly not narrow the `fsize` value and quiet the warning.

```
if (fsize >= 0 && (uintmax_t) fsize <= SIZE_MAX) {
```

If the cast to `uintmax_t` is unnecessarily wide, I'd expect the compiler to still emit efficient code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In the first part of your response: `To compare mixed signed types whose comparable ranges are no clearly tied, cast to uintmax_t.` I guess you either meant `mixed unsigned types` or `intmax_t` ?

Comment: @Droopycom No.  Mixed unsigned type is not a problem.  With any pairs of integer types where one is some signed type (not only `intmax_t`) and the other is some unsigned type and the positive range of the two is not certain of which has a greater max, then casting the signed one to the widest unsigned type (after knowing its value is not negative) makes for a correct compare.

Comment: I see. I thought the first part of your comment about signed integers didn't assume the  value was not negative.